# Importing error while building an app in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Actually, I am very newbie about Cordova. I am building a push-notification function(OneSignal) on my cordova project.

First, I created the cordova app like this :

```
C:\>cordova create newGenNo15 io.newgen.newGenNo15 NewGenNo15
C:\newGenNo15>cordova platforms add android

C:\newGenNo15>cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
```

And then, imported this to Eclipse.

```
File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace
```

But, I found errors in Java file.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem. But I couldn't make it.
Even I modified build.gradle file like adding classpath and compile, but I failed.

Do i have to solve this problem?

Comment: this happen due to eclipse cant find the classes in the plugin because plugin in not present in it. Try to add jar file of that plugin and then rebuild project.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't find any jar file in plug-in. I've just seen aar files or mda files. Can I handle these files?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extract `classes.jar` file from the OneSignal `.aar` file. However I recommend just sticking with the standard Cordova build command instead of using Eclipse.

`cordova build android --release`

If you must use an Android project to add custom Java code I recommend using Android Studio over Eclipse. [Google has stopped supporting Eclipse](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) since the end of 2015.